# Group with Index Only Scan and zero Heap Fetches takes 30 seconds

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a large table

```sql
=> \d balances_snapshots;
                                          Table "public.balances_snapshots"
    Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                    Default
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------
 user_id       | integer                     |           |          |
 asset_id      | text                        |           |          |
 timestamp     | timestamp without time zone |           |          | now()
 total_balance | numeric                     |           | not null |
 id            | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('balances_snapshots_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "balances_snapshots_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "balances_snapshots_asset_id_total_balance_positive_idx" btree (asset_id) WHERE total_balance > 0::numeric
    "balances_snapshots_timestamp_idx" btree ("timestamp")
    "balances_snapshots_total_balance_asset_id_idx" btree (total_balance, asset_id DESC)
    "balances_snapshots_user_id_idx" btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "balances_snapshots_asset_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (asset_id) REFERENCES assets(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    "balances_snapshots_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

And a simple query:

```
explain analyze select 'test' where
  'test' IN (
    SELECT asset_id FROM balances_snapshots WHERE total_balance > 0 GROUP BY asset_id
  );
```

which takes 30 seconds to execute on Google Cloud SQL 8 vCPU, 18 RAM despite it uses Index Only Scan with zero Heap Fetches:

```
 Result  (cost=5088867.27..5088867.28 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=31661.912..31663.750 rows=0 loops=1)
   One-Time Filter: (hashed SubPlan 1)
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Group  (cost=1000.60..5088861.49 rows=2310 width=9) (actual time=5.433..31652.313 rows=3455 loops=1)
           Group Key: balances_snapshots.asset_id
           ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.60..5088849.94 rows=4620 width=9) (actual time=5.431..31644.213 rows=9447 loops=1)
                 Workers Planned: 2
                 Workers Launched: 2
                 ->  Group  (cost=0.57..5087316.65 rows=2310 width=9) (actual time=0.035..23003.921 rows=3149 loops=3)
                       Group Key: balances_snapshots.asset_id
                       ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using balances_snapshots_asset_id_total_balance_positive_idx on balances_snapshots  (cost=0.57..4698961.54 rows=155342044 width=9) (actual time=0.033..12475.044 rows=125137693 loops=3)
                             Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.252 ms
 Execution Time: 31663.830 ms
(14 rows)
```

Is it normal for postgres to take 12 seconds on that and if yes, the only way to boost this is to migrate to partitioned table, right?

I understand that this query can be more efficient with where clause but the query above is extracted from bigger one just to identify the cause of problem. Here is the bigger query:

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM assets
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM assets a WHERE (
    a.last_updated_timestamp IS NULL OR
    a.last_updated_timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY')
  )
) AND (
  id IN (
    SELECT asset_id FROM balances_snapshots WHERE total_balance > 0 GROUP BY asset_id
  )
);
 Nested Loop  (cost=1005.03..5108401.69 rows=727 width=112) (actual time=214.597..32211.567 rows=1001 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1003.18..5104135.80 rows=727 width=20) (actual time=214.586..32197.553 rows=1001 loops=1)
         ->  Group  (cost=1000.60..5088861.49 rows=2310 width=9) (actual time=5.807..32080.773 rows=3455 loops=1)
               Group Key: balances_snapshots.asset_id
               ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.60..5088849.94 rows=4620 width=9) (actual time=5.805..32072.921 rows=9440 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 2
                     Workers Launched: 2
                     ->  Group  (cost=0.57..5087316.65 rows=2310 width=9) (actual time=0.032..23878.886 rows=3147 loops=3)
                           Group Key: balances_snapshots.asset_id
                           ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using balances_snapshots_asset_id_total_balance_positive_idx on balances_snapshots  (cost=0.57..4698961.54 rows=155342044 width=9) (actual time=0.031..12832.019 rows=125137693 loops=3)
                                 Heap Fetches: 0
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on assets a  (cost=2.58..6.60 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=0 loops=3455)
               Recheck Cond: (id = balances_snapshots.asset_id)
               Filter: ((last_updated_timestamp IS NULL) OR (last_updated_timestamp < (now() - '1 day'::interval)))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
               Heap Blocks: exact=3455
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on assets_pkey  (cost=0.00..2.58 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=2 loops=3455)
                     Index Cond: (id = balances_snapshots.asset_id)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on assets  (cost=1.86..5.87 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1001)
         Recheck Cond: (id = a.id)
         Heap Blocks: exact=1001
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on assets_pkey  (cost=0.00..1.86 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=2 loops=1001)
               Index Cond: (id = a.id)
 Planning Time: 0.889 ms
 Execution Time: 32212.740 ms
(25 rows)
```

PostgreSQL 13.4

Comment: Please *always* show your version of Postgres and the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, not just `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Consider instructions here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 1):

The unfortunate formulation of your original query with `IN` on a subquery aggregating all rows with `total_balance > 0` makes Postgres process `125137693` (!) rows, without need.

Use instead:

```
SELECT 'test'
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM balances_snapshots
   WHERE  total_balance > 0
   AND    asset_id = 'test'
   );
```

Just needs a single index-only scan on your existing index `balances_snapshots_asset_id_total_balance_positive_idx`. Faster by **multiple orders of magnitude**.

Integrated in your bigger query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   assets a
WHERE (a.last_updated_timestamp IS NULL OR
       a.last_updated_timestamp < (now() - interval '1 DAY'))
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM balances_snapshots b
   WHERE  b.total_balance > 0
   AND    b.asset_id = a.id
   );
```

Seeing that the filter on `last_updated_timestamp`hardly removes any rows, splitting up the query further is **futile**.

**If** the filter was selective, it might help some more to split the "ugly `OR`" into two (equivalent) `UNION ALL` SELECTs like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   assets a
WHERE  a.last_updated_timestamp IS NULL
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM balances_snapshots b
   WHERE  b.total_balance > 0
   AND    b.asset_id = a.id
   )
UNION ALL   
SELECT *
FROM   assets a
WHERE  a.last_updated_timestamp < (now() - interval '1 DAY')
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM balances_snapshots b
   WHERE  b.total_balance > 0
   AND    b.asset_id = a.id
   );
```

See:

- [Why is an OR statement slower than UNION?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/293836/why-is-an-or-statement-slower-than-union/293851#293851)

Aside: Working with `timestamp` (instead of `timestamptz`) and basing the filter on just `now()` makes your query depend on the time zone setting of the current session, which can introduce sneaky errors.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be doing any heap fetches, but it is still processing an eighth of a billion rows.  12 seconds for that is not bad.  Why it takes another 18 seconds to aggregate them and then finalize the parallel aggregates is less obvious. Maybe the task is not getting distributed evenly over the parallel workers for some reason.

But your larger query seems gross for more than one reason.  Since id is unique on assets, the first subquery is entirely unnecessary as its WHERE can be applied directly.  Also, the GROUP BY in the 2nd subquery is unnecessary.  The behavior of IN-lists automatically ignores duplicates, and manually specifying it just confuses the issue and precludes some optimizations. So that gives:

```
SELECT * FROM assets
WHERE (
    last_updated_timestamp IS NULL OR
    last_updated_timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY')
  )   
 AND (
  id IN (
    SELECT asset_id FROM balances_snapshots WHERE total_balance > 0
  )
);
```

In my hands this gives a pretty efficient plan if "assets" is much smaller than "balances_snapshots".  But it might be better yet to write it as a `EXISTS (SELECT ...)`.