# Seq scan on OR condition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I'm using PostgreSQL 11. I have a table with ~500к records and its size is around 2GB. If I'm running this query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT point.id
FROM "buildings_point" as point
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "equipment_equipment" as equipment ON (point.equipment_id = equipment.id)
WHERE (
    equipment.id = 4
    OR point.id = 4
);
```

And I do have both indexes in the `buildings_point` table:

```
"buildings_point_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"buildings_point_997b9956" btree (equipment_id)
```

For the `equipment_equipment` table I do have index by `id`:

```
"equipment_equipment_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

But the scheduler ran:
`Parallel Seq Scan on buildings_point point`
which took about 18 sec to walk through all 500к records. If I remove any of `equipment.id = 4` or `point.id = 4` query will take around 5 ms. Why does the scheduler not use both indexes?

Explain analyze output:

```
   ->  Sort  (cost=175133.54..175133.59 rows=19 width=4) (actual time=19163.682..19181.748 rows=3 loops=1)
         Sort Key: point.id
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Gather  (cost=2307.62..175133.14 rows=19 width=4) (actual time=3958.040..19181.729 rows=3 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 2
               Workers Launched: 2
               ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=1307.62..174131.24 rows=8 width=4) (actual time=8205.581..19155.693 rows=1 loops=3)
                     Hash Cond: (point.equipment_id = equipment.id)
                     Filter: ((equipment.id = 4) OR (point.id = 4))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 218243
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on buildings_point point  (cost=0.00..172111.33 rows=271333 width=8) (actual time=4.661..18838.772 rows=218244 loops=3)
                     ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=1116.56..1116.56 rows=15285 width=4) (actual time=52.361..52.364 rows=12229 loops=3)
                           Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1984kB
                           ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using buildings_equipment_pkey on equipment_equipment equipment  (cost=0.29..1116.56 rows=15285 width=4) (actual time=0.848..34.102 rows=12229 loops=3)
                                 Heap Fetches: 176
 Planning Time: 0.275 ms
 Execution Time: 19182.162 ms
```

Comment: You can get rid of the costly distinct if you turn the outer join into an `exists` condition.

Comment: @RonJohn I added an index description for the `equipment_equipment` table. What do you mean by "have you analyzed the tables lately"?

Comment: `ANALYZE buildings_point;` and `ANALYZE equipment_equipment;`.  Those commands "collect statistics" useful to the query optimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it all together, based on these **assumptions**:

- Referential integrity is enforced with a FK constraint, so you don't need to join to `equipment_equipment` at all.
- Both predicates are selective enough to benefit from an index. (Since `buildings_point.id` is the PK, that's at least true for `id = 4`, which returns exactly one row.)

Rewrite the ugly `OR` with `UNION` to make it faster:

```
SELECT id
FROM   buildings_point
WHERE  id = 4

UNION
SELECT id
FROM   buildings_point
WHERE  equipment_id = 4;
```

`UNION` removes a duplicate `id 4` if there should be one.

About the "ugly `OR`":

- [Why is an OR statement slower than UNION?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/293836/why-is-an-or-statement-slower-than-union/293851#293851)

Comment: Thank you for this link!

Answer (score 1):

You can just change `equipment.id = 4` into `equipment_id = 4`, and then you wouldn't need the join at all.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to such cases (`OR` in `WHERE` clause) can be `UNION` operator - in that case query planner will use `Index scan` for both queries.